# show variant type value in MessageBox

Tags: c++, directshow, win32com

huh i got a small prob in fact i want to be able to see list of my plugged devices 
i want to see them at the first place in MessageBox() 
but this variant irks me (^_^) i have tried  many ways but without result

```
    IMoniker *tmpMonk=NULL;
ULONG done;
VARIANT varName;
while(this->deviceClassEnum->Next(1,&tmpMonk,&done)==S_OK)
{
    IPropertyBag *tmpBag=NULL;
    tmpMonk->BindToStorage(0,0,IID_IPropertyBag,(void **)&tmpBag);
    VariantInit(&varName);
    checkIt(tmpBag->Read(L"FriendlyName",&varName,0));
            // this i wana see what is inside but huuuuuuuuuuuuuh
    MessageBox(this->app,TEXT((LPCSTR)varName.bstrVal),"",NULL);
    VariantClear(&varName);
    tmpBag->Release();
}
```

secondly how to be able to switch from device to another . from 
whatever menu or list

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `MessageBoxW` instead of `MessageBox`. And remove the casts. So it will look like:

```
MessageBoxW(this->app, varName.bstrVal , L"", NULL);
```

This is a problem in character encoding; strings used in COM are of type `BSTR`, which can be used the same as `PWSTR` / `PCWSTR` types. This is incompatible with `PCSTR`.

Remember that casts simply tell the compiler "hey I know what I'm doing, shut up". Except the compiler's messages were actually trying to help you, you told them to go away. Next time listen to them.

Comment: thx tenfour it works i have never known that MessageBoxW existed huh   should i put those names in collection to be able to switch from device to another ?

Comment: Every/Most(?) Windows-API function exists in two variants, *A and *W. Depending on whether you have UNICODE defined in your project settings, the windows header files define "MessageBox" as either MessageBoxW or MessageBoxA. That's for your convenience, but you can always call the appropriate version explicitly.